# How to update an HTML Table interactively upon selection of one of 4 form fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML page with a form and a table on it.
Using PHP, I would like to use a set of 4 of the form fields to build a mySql query to update the table in real time as the user selects any of the 4 fields.
The query should be built and executed upon the change of any of the 4 form fields.
Here is my code for the form fields:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table cellspacing="0" border-width="1px" height= "28">
        <tr>
            <td class="style4" style="width: 160px">
                <strong>Location
            </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="style5" style="width: 150px">
                <select name="Location" style="width: 150px" onchange="SetQuery.php">
                <option hidden selected>Select a Location</option>
                <?php   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myLocations)){
                            echo '<option value="' . $record['location'] . '">' . $record['location'] . '</option>';
                }
                ?>

                </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 59px">
        <tr>
            <td class="style4" style="width: 160px">
                <strong>Customer
            </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="style5" style="width: 150px">
                <input name="Customer" type="text" style="width: 150px" onchange="SetQuery.php">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="style4" style="width: 160px">
                <strong>Family 
            </strong> 
            </td>
            <td class="style5" style="width: 150px">
                <input name="Family" type="text" style="width: 150px" onchange="SetQuery.php">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="style4" style="width: 160px">
                <strong>Customer Part Number 
            </strong> 
            </td>
            <td class="style5" style="width: 150px">
                <input name="CustomerPartNumber" type="text" style="width: 150px" onchange="SetQuery.php">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I was thinking of using the onchange function to call a routine (I called it SetQuery.php) to build the query and update the table.
I do not know how to write the routine to update the table upon each selection of one of my 4 fields.

Here is my code to build the table initially. It is just a basic query to get all records just to get things going. In proper flow, the table will not populate until one of the 4 fields are chosen.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="font-size: xx-small">
<tr>
 <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Description</font></th>
 <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">West Part Number</font></th>
 <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cavities</font></th>
 <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Cycle Time</font></th>
 <th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Material</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo mysql_result($result2,$i,0); ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo mysql_result($result2,$i,1); ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo mysql_result($result2,$i,2); ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo mysql_result($result2,$i,3); ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo mysql_result($result2,$i,4); ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help with this onchange routine? I need help in writing it and where to put it and how to call it.

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Look i did not read through all of your code so i dont know if there is any mistake but i did read what you want, so i will give you hint, you are using method post, and when you use method post, you actually build a `$_POST` array, so just count number of element in the array, if you are confuse, just use print_r($_POST) in the action file and you will know what i am trying to say, and to make your job easy, make sure column name matches the field of the name in the form, so you dont have to type much, you can just give dyanamic value to variable, and it will run create a query according ...

Comment: ....... to the column you selected. Hope you will be able to do it your self or some body will answer you wish you luck

Comment: Thanks, arif. Actually, the post will be used at the end of the process when the whole form is filled out. The form is very big and I only showed the four fields for simplicity. The table that will be updated with the onchange routine will be showing the user information to help him fill out the rest of the form. Once the form is done, the info will be written to my master database table upon posting.

Comment: ok, i did not get fully, correct me if i am wrong, so that's what i understood so far, let's say the user select certain number of field, than you want fill the other field in the form, so you can help user to fill out the form, OR....... you want to insert the value in the database, as soon as user select the four option, and than keep on upating that row, I understood the master database part full, that one is simple i think you know how to do it.

Comment: Not quite. The form has the 4 fields in question. Then to the right of the form is my html table.
If the user selects the first form field (Location) then the table to the right will be populated with all of the records that match the Location that he selected.
Then, if he enters the second form field (Customer) the table to the right will be populated with all the records that match the  Location and the Customer.
All of the form fields will be populated by the user, none programmatically.

Comment: I posted a solution have a look

Answer (score 2):

So far what i got, you have some field in the form, and one table, which will display the result according to number of field, 
English is not the first language, so if any confusion let me know

Add onchange event with every input field which will call the javascript function, and that function will sent the value to the php file

```
<input name="Your Field Name" onchange="setValue(this.value);">
```

setValue is the name for the javascript function which going to set the value for you when ever it changes

> if you dont know how to set it, read this link although link does not
>   completly solve your problem but it will good for you know how to set
>   the value, 
>   http:stackoverflow.comquestions22461324onchange-change-the-variable-in-php

**than create ajax call, if you dont know just google it not every every hard thing to do**.

> Now comes to php file, as i told this code will only work, when you
>   have one table

Now you also have to imagine these two cases, what you want to allow

**First Case --** even if the user jump the field, you still want him to show the restult,
 ***what do i mean by that ? -*** for example lets say user type some thing, in the first field and than instead of typing some thing in the second and third field, he jumped to the fourth field now what you want you want to run the query according to the first field  and fourth field

**Second Case --** You actually dont care, weather he jump or not you only going  to show the result, when he typed first and than he type second field and than third, like in a system basic shell work in both condition you dont have to do any thing,

> Only one thing is important, instead of typing the query, we are going to create a query in a way that it depends on how many values are set, means we are going to Generate query according to the value which are set.

**Before you go ahead keep this in mind, this is how normal sql query with AND LOOK LIKE**

> SELECT * FROM myTableName WHERE name = 'my name' AND street = 'this is
>   my street'

**just read the code and make sure you read the comment in the code as well.**

***and let's assume our variable names are $name, $address, $street and $qualification***

```
$name='my name';
//$address='some where on earth';
$street='this is my street';
//$qualification='i am very much qualified';

//now create the array only with the values which are not empty,
//I am using empty with this example you can use any thing.
if(!empty($name)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND name = '$name'";
if(!empty($address)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND address = '$address'";
if(!empty($street)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND street = '$street'";
if(!empty($qualification)) $query_string_second_part[]=" AND qualification = '$qualification'";

//hand type the first part for the query
$query_string_First_Part= "SELECT * FROM myTableName WHERE";
//Implode the array, if you want to see how it look like use echo,
$query_string_second_part= implode(" ", $query_string_second_part);
//as you can see we are adding AND with every value, so we need to remove the first 
//with one space
//Make sure you give space in the second parameter. else it wont work means "" not correct but " " is correct
//Hint --> use one space in between the double qoutes
$query_string_second_part=  preg_replace("/AND/", " ", $query_string_second_part, 1);

//Join the first and second part together to create a full query
$query_string=$query_string_First_Part.$query_string_second_part;
echo ($query_string);//see how our query look like at the moment
```

Comment: The 4 way query is working fine. Now what I need to do is to display the results in a table of fixed height with a vertical scroll bar. 
ALSO, I need the program to read and display a bunch of records at a time and when the user scrolls down far enough, the program will read more records from the table and allow the scrolling to proceed. Then, if the user scrolls up, the program will fetch more records to display st the top of the table. Since there could be many hundreds of records in the query, we don't want to hold all of them in memory.

Comment: @rtemen what do mean four way query is working fine?? and i just checked your profile why you never accept the solution, I dont like this on stack, so i will not touch your question, as a new question, and what you ask in the comment, just create a box with max-height and you are dont, scroll will appear by it self

Comment: What I meant is the solution you shared with the query built using the 4 parameters is working for me.
I am rather new at this forum, and I do not know how to 'accept the solution'. Can you point me to the instructions on how to proceed at this point?

Comment: @rtemen sorry i was rude in the last comment, as i thought you were one of those who dont appericciate that other people helpling you out, most of the people i know of working and mean while posting comment or solution for other, i was on the job as well, when i posted solution for you, to accept the solution, just scroll up to the solution (on the top) you will see two arrow and tick, by clicking on the tick, you can accept the solution, if you dont get it, just google it, and second your new problem post a new question, .............

Comment: ..........at moment i am busy, your question is not that complicited, you will get the solution, when i am free i will check your profile, and that question is unanswered i willl post some thing, but i thing you will get the solution with in few minutes, make sure add html tag as with your question, and if you want to try, try it your self, create a div with the max height, and give scroll you are done, (if i understood your question correctly), sorry again wish you luck

Comment: Thanks, @arif_suhail_123. I did get the scrolling working.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that onchange will trigger a javascript function and not load something from your webserver. For that to happen you'll need more code and I'd advise you to put that code in a separate file or at least in a separate javascript block.

My second advise would be to start using jQuery for now. I'm not sure if it is the best starting point but historically it is widely used, fast and contains everything you need for now.

Start by reading this on the use of the change event:
https://api.jquery.com/change/

And this on using AJAX for loading your changes from PHP:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Now, you can either have your SetQuery.php return HTML and inject this directly or have it return a data set and convert this to HTML on the front-end. If you don't know JSON, read up on it.

Last but not least, you might want to start by using a framework. PHP has a lot of choices and I think Laravel is a nice one to start with. It has a great learning curve for starters and the free tutorials will get you started on any low to mid-sized application.

Kind regards.